# How secure is the information in an URL?

Tags: security, url, https, request

From what I have learned, you should never pass any critical information in the URL while making an HTTPS request, because it is not as strongly encoded as the body is. But after some research it seems like this idea is not true anymore (or never was) ?

There are multiple reason why you would want to use a BODY and not the URL, would it be size, the risk of saving the password in local history etc., but it seems like my knowledge on the matter is a bit outdated.

What are the current differences, on a modern browser, between the information in the URL and the BODY of an HTTPS request? Is it any different than what was the case with HTTP, back in the old days ?

I have ask multiple AI, that seem to give me differents anwsers.
I have checked google with "Difference between the BODY and url in HTTPS" but the answers where disappointing.

Comment: "Secure" *from what*, specifically?  Are you talking about hiding information from the user?  Showing information to the user but hiding it from a 3rd party observer watching network traffic?  Something else?

Comment: For HTTPS, everything in the URL (from the path onward) is encrypted in exactly the same way as the rest of the content. It's not stronger or weaker. The problem with putting sensitive content in the URL is that information is often logged at the server side, so this information will appear in the logs. Logs tend not to be well protected, and often get passed around for analysis

Comment: Thanks you @President James K. Polk , This is exactly what I was wondering. So the vulnerability is not at all in the encoding as I was lead to believe, but with everything around it. Do you know if it was the case with HTTP that only the body was encoded? I wonder why I had that false presumption

Comment: HTTP is a cleartext protocol, nothing is encrypted.

Comment: Seem I really was given some really bad info at my first job. Thank you for the clarification James